# best practices- analysis server ans sql browser

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I read somewhere:

> Analysis services should run under
> network account
>
> Ensure SQL
> Browser uses a domain account

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find documentation dictating those restrictions on those 2 services.  These two articles seem to give some discretion to the user on how they want to set them up:

**SQL Server Configuration - Service Accounts**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281953.aspx

**SQL Server - Setting Up Windows Service Accounts**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx

The only caveat I see is for the Analysis Services service in a failover cluster configuration, it says `For failover cluster configurations, use the domain user account`.